# Why is render() being called twice in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently attempting to make an app with one screen where the background of the screen is taken up by a map centered on the user's current coordinates. In the below code, I have saved the longitude and longitude as null within the state of the App class component. Then, I use the inherited method 'componentDidMount()' to update the state with the user's current location, and finally in render() I use this.state.latitude and this.state.longitude to inform the values for latitude and longitude for MapView.

The code does not compile. Using console.log, I have isolated the problem to be that render() is being called twice, and my console.log statement first outputs the null value to the console, and then outputs the user's current location.

So two questions.

1) Why does console.log output values to the console two different times, one of which is the state value passed in and one of which is the state value updated by componentDidMount()?

2) How can I run the function navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() to save the user's current location and pass it to MapView so that the code compiles in the first place?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { latitude: null, longitude: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles2.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: this.state.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />

        {console.log(this.state.latitude)}
        {console.log(this.state.longitude)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: At first sight, I see <View> tag is missing inside return.

Comment: @Rama those look like formatting errors caused by not properly indenting the code with the 4-spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React will re-render whenever your component updates via `state` or props. In your `componentDidMount()` you are calling `setState()`, so at some point after that (since it is asynchronous), your component will need to update for the new `state` so it renders again.

The first `render()` occurs when your component mounts. This is where you will see whatever the initial values of `latitude` and `longitude` are on your state.

After your component has mounted, your call to `setState()` will update `state` with the new values of `latitude` and `longitude` so your component will `render()` a second time where you will see the new values of `latitude` and `longitude`.

EDIT:

If you want to avoid the first display of `latitude` and `longitude` (NB. It will still render twice) you could conditionally render i.e.

```
render() {
    if(!this.state.longitude) {
      return <View>Loading...</View>;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles2.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: this.state.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any feedback on how this code can pass in the updated longitude/latitude so that it renders the first time with the correct coordinates?

Comment: @SarthakAgrawal you could conditionally render. I will edit answer to include an example

Answer (score 2):

The render method is called always that a value from state or props is changed

Answer (score 0):

#2 is easy - you mounted the component (render 1), then "componentDidMount" runs after the component "did mount", then waits for the position to be returned, which is render 2. Remember that React, by design, will render *a lot*.

The very premise is that it takes what was normally prohibitively expensive (updating the whole DOM), and instead manages its own "virtual DOM", which is extremely cheap to update. The expensive DOM updates are optimised into only updating the parts that were changed, so you're free to re-run `render()` a whole lot. You'll sometimes find render methods that are slow that you may need to go back and optimise, but they're the exception, not the rule.

#1 actually describes your code working perfectly. `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous (via its callback), and it correctly gets the lat/lng. If it's throwing an error simply rendering it, it's a problem with your JSX. Try simplifying it, e.g. `<p>{this.state.longitude}, {this.state.latitude}</p>` to see that it's rendering the correct values, then build from there.