# Render method is called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm totally new to React and now I'm following [react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) which makes a tic-toe game. I'm trying to follow it too. The problem I have is that render method is called twice and I don't know why.

**Board Component**

```
 export class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      Xturn: true,
    };
  }

  changeTurn(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    if (this.calculateWinner(squares)) {
      return;
    } else {
      squares[i] = this.state.Xturn ? "X" : "Y";
      this.setState({
        squares: squares,
        Xturn: !this.state.Xturn,
      });
    }
  }

  calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
      if (squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
        return squares[a];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  createTable(rows) {
    let table = [];
    let child_key = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      let children = [];

      for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        children.push(
          <Square
            key={child_key}
            indicator={child_key}
            value={this.state.squares[child_key]}
            handleClick={(d) => this.changeTurn(d)}
          />
        );
        child_key++;
      }

      table.push(<div className="board-row">{children}</div>);
    }
    return table;
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    const winner = this.calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
    if (winner) {
      console.log("done");
      alert("we have a winner");
    }
    return <div className="board">{this.createTable(3)}</div>;
  }
}
```

And it's  **Square component**

```
 export class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  OnClick = () => {
    this.props.handleClick(this.props.indicator);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="square" onClick={this.OnClick}>
        {this.props.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When a player put three of them in a row (wins), why I get two alerts (we have a winner) ??

this is what i get in **console**

```
render
done
render
done
```

Why React calls render() two time??

Comment: I have literally just copied your code and used the rest of the code from the tutorial and it worked perfectly with one "we have a winner" message. Either your `Square` class is calling `handleClick` twice, or you forgot to clear your console. Maybe it's worth putting your `Square` class code on here.

Comment: @NelsonYeung ok i'm gonna add it

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all, here's my code, where the JS is copied exactly from yours: https://codepen.io/nelsyeung/pen/poJXgJp?editors=1111 I've tested this on Firefox and Edge, both on the latest version. Can you let me know whether you still see the problem on CodePen?

Comment: @NelsonYeung That's interesting. You copied exactly my code and it gives just one alert. But my code in local host running Firefox and Chrome last versions gives two alerts. how that's possible ?? did u ran my code in ur localhost to see the result ??

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behaviour. You may refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html for the lifecycle methods. Basically, first the constructor is loaded then the render method. To elaborate a bit you can view also this answer - [Why is render() being called twice in ReactNative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082423/why-is-render-being-called-twice-in-reactnative). In your case first the initial values are called, then the setState takes place. If you dont want to display something just use condition.